# How to get file content in java

Tags: java, file

My question is how to get file content in class File (java)

for example, I have :

```
File folder = new File("BitTorrent");
for (final File SubFile : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (!SubFile.isDirectory()) {
        **// HOW TO READ ALL THE CONTENT OF SUBFILE WITHOUT USING ITS PATH.**
    }
}
```

What I mean is that are there any get method can do this. We can use these codes below instead, but I don't like that

```
Path p = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
byte[] fileArray = Files.readAllBytes(p);
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are we supposed to suggest other means to read files until there is one "you like"? Or will you explain what you actually want to achieve, and why you "don't like that"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using the path of the file as here :

```
Path p = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
byte[] fileArray = Files.readAllBytes(p);
```

you can open a `DataInputStream` and read all the content in a byte array :

```
File folder = new File("BitTorrent");
for (final File SubFile : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (!SubFile.isDirectory()) {
        **// HOW TO READ ALL THE CONTENT OF SUBFILE WITHOUT USING ITS PATH.**
         byte[] bytes= new byte[(int)SubFile.length()];
         DataInputStream dataIs = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(SubFile));
         dataIs.readFully(bytes);
         // here bytes has the content
    }
}
```